# Image resizing best practices for google vision product search

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-vision

Would like to know best practices for processing and uploading reference images for vision product search.

I found some documentation here: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/supported-files#image_sizing but have more specific questions.

If an image is smaller than 640 x 480, should I upsize it?

Should I add padding to get to exactly 640 x 480 (or 480 x640) or would resizing one dimension to get to the minimum number of pixels be sufficient?

Would like to get the best results from a query and also make all reference images as "similar" as possible, so that when I submit a query image, the results are not biased towards any kind of size or dimension.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a larger image, you can use the larger image instead of your smaller image. If all you have is the smaller image, then stretching it to be a certain size isn't going to help. Don't add padding since that wouldn't add anything of value. Also, don't stretch one dimension to reach a certain number of pixels.

It's okay for your reference images to be different sizes.